# Unable to resolve ${file.separator} programmatically to read property path

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to read a property which contains a file path including logged in user name in path as below.

test.file = ${file.separator}test${file.separator}${user.name}${file.separator}file.txt

I am able to read file with OS specific path (/ - unix or -windows) when I read the property using @Value annotation in a class and when used it in pom.xml as an argument..

When i read this as regular property from property file, spring is reading it as another string value which is expected.

But if i pass this value to File constructor, ${file.separator} doesn't get resolved..

what is the best way to represent file separator in a property file? I want to avoid .replace technique to replace a variable with File.separator in code.

Comment: Please use escape slashes as it's a special character. `\\`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a file separator which is platform neutral then, we have been using `/` separator without any problem.

```
path=C:/Users/<user_name>/myconfig.properties
path=/Users/<user_name>/myconfig.properties
```

The following code always returns true on both systems.

```
finput = new File(prop.getProperty("path"));
System.out.println(finput.exists());
```

Comment: for replacing <user_name>, i still need to use replace method in code with the value of system property (user.name).                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                    
Not sure how Maven interprets both user.name and File.separator when they are passed as arguments in pom.xml

Comment: The essence of properties file is to take the configurable things out of the code. It doesn't have any processing power on its own.

Comment: I ended up solving this by using apache common config with property as /test/${sys:user.name}/file.txt where sys: is interpreted as a system variable by apache commons config and resolve to a logged in user value.